# How to push specific bits into a new file?

Tags: scripts, files

Is there any way for me to push specific bits into a new file, without creating temporary files and then concatenating them?

For example, I want to create a 10 octets file, where the first three are set to `4`, the next two to `7` and the final five to `32`.

> 0000.0100 0000.0100 0000.0100 0000.0111 0000.0111 0010.0000 0100.0000 0010.0000 0010.0000 0010.0000

I need a solution that would allow me to create large files, where specific bits are repeated many times.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85951/how-do-i-create-a-file-with-a-given-structure

Comment: @Caesium The answer to that question won't work for me. I need to create large files, where the specific bits are repeated very many times.

Comment: @Caesium Unless there's some (preferably pre-packaged) shell solution, I should just concatenate multiple files. I don't think writing C or Perl is justifiable for this problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple in Python. You can start the interactive interpreter by just typing `python` and do something like this:

```
>>> open("test.bin", "wb").write("\4\4\4\7\7\32\32\32\32\32")
```

`'wb'` means "open the file for writing binary data to it", merely opening the file with `w` will assume you want to write *text* to it.

Note these are *octal* numbers (`\32` is `0x1a`, or 26)! They can also be hexadecimal (`\xff`), and you can save some typing by doing something like this:

```
>>> "\x00" * 4 + "\x09"
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x09'
```

The normal operator precedence applies.

For more data, you can use lists of decimal integers - which I find easier to read and type:

```
>>> d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> ''.join(chr(i) for i in d)
'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05'
```

If you prefer using `python3`, you'd use `bytes()` like this:

```
>>> bytes([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Of course 'arithmetic' works as you would expect:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] * 2 + [9] * 4 + range(4)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> range(10, 0, -3)
[10, 7, 4, 1]
```

Binary, orcal and hexadecimal literals are written like this:

```
0b1100 == 0o14 == 12 == 0xc
```

(Or `014` if you prefer)

If you want to do some complicated stuff, open the file first and then gradually write to it:

```
>>> f = open("test.bin", "wb")
>>> f.write("\xff" * 100)
>>> for i in range(10):
...     f.write("\xff\xfa\x03")
...
>>> f.close()
```

And if you want to script it, you can use the `-c` switch to invoke the code directly from the command line:

```
python -c "open('test.bin', 'wb').write(''.join(chr(i) for i in [1, 2, 3]))"
```

Answer (score 2):

In ruby, writing the pattern 10 times:

```
File.open('bits','w') do |f|
    10.times do
        f << ([0x04]*3+[0x07]*2+[0x20]*5).pack('C*')
    end
end
```

By writing to the file on each iteration, we only ever hold a single copy of the bit pattern in memory. That way you can write arbitrarily large files by changing the `10.times` to `10000.times` etc.

So from the command line:

```
$ ruby -e "File.open('bits','w'){|f|10.times{f<<([0x04]*3+[0x07]*2+[0x20]*5).pack('C*')}}"
```

Then check the file:

```
$ xxd -b bits 
0000000: 00000100 00000100 00000100 00000111 00000111 00100000  ..... 
0000006: 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00000100 00000100      ..
000000c: 00000100 00000111 00000111 00100000 00100000 00100000  ...   
0000012: 00100000 00100000 00000100 00000100 00000100 00000111    ....
0000018: 00000111 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000  .     
000001e: 00000100 00000100 00000100 00000111 00000111 00100000  ..... 
0000024: 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00000100 00000100      ..
000002a: 00000100 00000111 00000111 00100000 00100000 00100000  ...   
0000030: 00100000 00100000 00000100 00000100 00000100 00000111    ....
0000036: 00000111 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000  .     
000003c: 00000100 00000100 00000100 00000111 00000111 00100000  ..... 
0000042: 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00000100 00000100      ..
0000048: 00000100 00000111 00000111 00100000 00100000 00100000  ...   
000004e: 00100000 00100000 00000100 00000100 00000100 00000111    ....
0000054: 00000111 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000  .     
000005a: 00000100 00000100 00000100 00000111 00000111 00100000  ..... 
0000060: 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000
```

See the documentation for Array.pack [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack).

Comment: I gave you a +1, but I'll pick Stefano's answer since I know Python but not Ruby.